# Cambiar columna automaticamente EF

Tags: c#, code-first

Tengo un campo llamado Status: el cual puede recibir 3 valores .¿Como podría cambiar el valor de ese campo dependiendo la condición de otro campo que esta en mi base de datos? Estoy utilizando entity framework 5 EF.

Imaginemos que tengo el siguiente model.

```
public class batches
(
  [Key]
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public DateTime Start {get;set;}

  public DateTime End {get;set;}

  public String Status {get;set;}
)
```

Quisiera que al llenar el campo Start el valor de la columna status me cambie a In Process y cuando llene el campo End la columna Status me cambie a complete ect.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer que el modelo evalue la informacion de estos campo y en consecuencia te retorne lo que deseas en cuanto realizas un GET al campo de Status.

```
private string _status;
public string Status
{
    get
    {
        //CAMBIAR DECISION A LO QUE DESEAS EVALUAR
        if (true)
        {

            return _status = "In Process";
        }
        else
        {

            return _status = "complete";
        }
    }
    set
    {
        _status = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias muy ultil la respuesta